# Plot multiple polynomial regression curve

Tags: r, plot, regression

I am trying to plot only a few regression lines and not any of the points. (No `fitted`, because I have over 7 thousand points.) I know how to do this with linear regressions, but not with polynomial regression. My data is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xslfl30oh4vbpk5/plot_data.csv?dl=0). With a few linear regressions:

```
plot_data=read.csv("plot_data.csv") #read data

#linear regressions
Off_linear=lm(Z_Salary~OBPM,data=plot_data) 
Def_linear=lm(Z_Salary~DBPM,data=plot_data)
Tot_linear=lm(Z_Salary~BPM,data=plot_data)   

#try to plot. This works. Not sure how to add legend
termplot(Def_linear, ylab='Z_Salary',xlab='BPM',ylim=c(-2, 2))
abline(Off_linear)
abline(Tot_linear,col='blue')
```

[image: Plot]

However I cannot do this if I try to create polynomial regressions. I want the same kind of plot with these regressions, but `termplot` does work with independent variables together and does them separately.

```
Off_exp=lm(Z_Salary~OBPM+I(OBPM^2),data=plot_data)
Def_exp=lm(Z_Salary~DBPM+I(DBPM^2),data=plot_data)
Tot_exp=lm(Z_Salary~BPM+I(BPM^2),data=plot_data)
```

Comment: Make x values that you want to plot for then get the predicted values using the predict function.

Comment: @Dason can you explain more precisely how to do it.
I create a new x values but it still does not work.
`nd=data.frame(x=seq(0,8,length=8))
test=predict(Def_exp,newdata=nd)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dason already gave you the hint. Find below some code to make it work.

```
Off_exp=lm(Z_Salary~OBPM+I(OBPM^2),data=plot_data)
x=seq(from=range(plot_data$OBPM)[1], to=range(plot_data$OBPM)[2])
y=predict(Off_exp, newdata=list(OBPM=x))
plot(x, y, type="l", col="blue", xlab="OBPM", ylab="Z_Salary")
legend("topleft", legend="d2", col="blue", lty=1, title="polys")
```

It would look something like this:
[image: resulting plot]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response, however the `y=predict(Off_exp, newdata=list(OBPM=x.grid))` does not work, because I do not have anything set as x.grid yet. If I set `x.grid=OPBM`, then I get an error when plotting saying "'x' and 'y' lengths differ", which makes sense because Y is length of OBPM while X is like 20

Comment: I've corrected the response, sorry for a silly typo. Cheers.